# Only Push onto array once versus pushing to array every time condition is met

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, algorithm

I am importing excel files that contain customer orders like so

```js
onFileChange(event: any) {
    const inputFile: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(event.target); 
    const fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = (event: any) => {
      const binaryString: string = event.target.result;
      const workBook: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(binaryString, { type: 'binary', sheetStubs: true}); 
      /* sheetstubs true supposedly shows empty cells but isn't */
      console.log(typeof binaryString)

      const workSheetName: string = workBook.SheetNames[0];
      console.log(workSheetName)
      const workSheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = workBook.Sheets[workSheetName];

      this.data = <Array>(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workSheet, { header: 1, blankrows: true }));


    };
    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(inputFile.files[0]);
    console.log(this.data)
  }
```

The way the excel files are imported an object of arrays where each array is a row of the excel sheet.

In the following code snippet, I am searching for items in a column to identify the column in an excel sheet that has the shoe brands requested by a customer in the code

```js
for (var i=0; i<this.data.length; i++){
      if (this.data[i].indexOf('Adidas') != -1) {
        var manIndex = this.data[i].indexOf('Adidas')
        for( var j = 0; j<this.data.length; j++){
          this.manufactArray.push(this.data[j][manIndex])
        }

      }
      else if (this.data[i].indexOf('Puma') != -1) {
        var manIndex = this.data[i].indexOf('Puma')
        for (var j=0; j<this.data.length; j++) {
          this.manufactArray.push(this.data[j][manIndex])
        }
      }
      else if (this.data[i].indexOf('Nike') != -1) {
        var manIndex = this.data[i].indexOf('Nike')
        for(var j = 0; j<this.data.length; j++){
          this.manufactArray.push(this.data[j][manIndex])
        }
      }
      }

    }
```

this works in that it pushes all of the items in the relevant column into the array but it does so every time the conditions are met and as such the same column is pushed into the array a bunch of times as opposed to only pushing the column items once. Is there a way maybe using the `%` or other function so that the column is only pushed into the array one time? So if I had a customer sheet come in like this:

[image: Example Order]

I would want the array to have `[Nike, Adidas, Puma, Puma, Asics, Nike]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use a Set. You probably don't want to check if it is in the array before you add it, because then you may have O(n²) time complexity, which can be undesirable.

You can add it to a set, and return as a set, or if needed, return as an array:

```js
const mySet = new Set();

mySet.add(123);
console.log([...mySet]);

mySet.add("hello world");
console.log([...mySet]);

mySet.add(123);
console.log([...mySet]);
```

I would have just used `console.log(mySet)` but for some reason StackOverflow can't print out its value (unlike Node.js or Chrome). But then it shows how to convert the set back to an array.  You can also use `Array.from(mySet)`.

So in your code, you probably have:

```
this.manufactSet = new Set();
```

and in the loop:

```
this.manufactSet.add(this.data[j][manIndex]);
```

and after the loop, you can set it back to an array:

```
this.manufactArray = [...this.manufactSet];
```

But I don't quite get your code:

```
for (var i=0; i<this.data.length; i++){
      if (this.data[i].indexOf('Adidas') != -1) {
        var manIndex = this.data[i].indexOf('Adidas')
        for( var j = 0; j<this.data.length; j++){
          this.manufactArray.push(this.data[j][manIndex])
        }
```

Why when you found `Adidas`, then you push *everything* into the result?
Shouldn't you do:

```
for (var i=0; i<this.data.length; i++){
      if (this.data[i].indexOf('Adidas') != -1) {
        var manIndex = this.data[i].indexOf('Adidas')
        this.manufactArray.push(this.data[i][manIndex])
```

?

Is `this.data[i]` a string that might have  "Cool Adidas NMD hard to find"... and once you find the "location" of `Adidas`, why do you just push that character into the result?

Don't you want to push the whole string into the result?

```
for (var i=0; i<this.data.length; i++){
      if (this.data[i].indexOf('Adidas') != -1) {
        var manIndex = this.data[i].indexOf('Adidas')
        this.manufactArray.push(this.data[i])
```

So after checking what data[i] is and what you would like to do, seems like this is what you want to do:

Note that you mentioned you actually want the manufacturer to appear more than once, like `["Adidas", "Adidas", "Nike", "Puma", "Nike"]`, so I won't use a set as the result below:

```
const someManufacturers = new Set(['Adidas', 'Puma', 'Nike']);

function getColumnNumber() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < this.data[i].length; j++) {
      if (someManufacturers.has(this.data[i][j])) return j;
    }
  }
}
var manufacturerColumnNumber = getColumnNumber();

for (var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
  this.manufactArray.push(this.data[i][manufacturerColumnNumber]);
}
```

Actually, there is a better way to write it now in ES6:

```
const someManufacturers = new Set(['Adidas', 'Puma', 'Nike']);

function getColumnNumber() {
  for (const row of this.data) {
    for (let i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
      if (someManufacturers.has(row[i])) return i;
    }
  }
}
var manufacturerColumnNumber = getColumnNumber();

for (const row of this.data) {
  this.manufactArray.push(row[manufacturerColumnNumber]);
}
```

I think I see what you mean by "pushing" every time instead of once. You mean if you see `Adidas`, you push the whole column values to the array, and the next row, you see `Nike`, and you push the whole column values to the array again. You could have just returned if you put that in a function. So once you see `Adidas`, then just push all values in that column to the array and return from the function.

Comment: can you include a snippet?

Comment: hmmm this doesn't necessarily answer my question, I am fine with having duplicate brands in the column itself but I don't want the entire column pushed multiple times once the algorithm identifies a "common" brand I want that entire column to be copied into the array

Comment: ohh i see what the question is I will update my question

Comment: So basically I am getting this information from excel sheets importing them with the `xlsx` library how the files are imported is as an object of arrays with each array in the object representing a row of the excel file

Comment: so the first index [i] is the row and the second index [j] is the cell in that row if that makes sense

Comment: so `this.data[i]` is not a string. It is an array, and one entry  in the array can be just `"Adidas"` and nothing else. Is this the case?   *So*, are you just checking which column is a manufacturer name, say column 4, and then you push all cells of column 4 into the result?

Comment: please check this part: So, are you just checking which column is a manufacturer name, say column 4, and then you push all cells of column 4 into the result?

Comment: I am just trying to identify the manufacturer column and then push all of the cells in that column into the array

Comment: please see last part answer. And you are saying you don't want to add "Adidas" multiple times, but just once. So the final result should have all distinct manufacturer names (or brandnames)

Comment: no it is fine to have adidas multiple times if adidas shows multiple times in the excel sheet my issue was that the entire column itself was being added multiple times the way I was trying to do it

Comment: So what is the final desirable result? Something like `["Adidas", "Adidas", "Nike", "Adidas", "Asics"]` ?

Comment: Yes, the brands were included in the if statements solely to identify the manufacturer columns because those shoe brands are very common so if I look for the column that has one of those values I can generally assume that that column is the manufacturer column, however I want the column in its entirety to be pushed into the array, duplicate manufacturers included if they are included in the order because they may ask for multiple products from the same manufacturer

Comment: So what is the final desirable result? Something like `[ ["Adidas", "Adidas", "Nike", "Adidas", "Asics"],  ["Nike", "Nike", "Puma"], ["Asics", "Asics"] ]` ?

Comment: updated the question again for clarity I just want the column in one single array

Comment: ok, then my answer works except just the "Set" part... you don't need or want the Set

Comment: is this final version what you wanted?